# ComboBox Filter Backspace Not Working as Expected

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm implementing a filterable `Combobox` but have been running into trouble. My implementation below works initially for typing to filter results but once you select an item from the dropdown it becomes difficult to backspace characters or delete all for the `Textbox` filter. It appears like the `Combobox` auto-selects the originally selected value and resets to that on each button press. Below is the minimum code to reproduce the issue which will demonstrate the issue clearer. Simply select a value from the dropdown and then backspace or delete text to try to select a new value.

With the following test data;

```
public IEnumerable<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        List<Fruit> temp = new List<Fruit>
        {
            new Fruit(Name = "apple"),
            new Fruit(Name = "banana"),
            new Fruit(Name = "grape"),
            new Fruit(Name = "lemon"),
            new Fruit(Name = "strawberry")
        };
        Fruits = temp;
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Fruit(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Updated FilteredComboBox code;

```
public class FilteredComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumSearchLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "MinimumSearchLength",
      typeof(int),
      typeof(FilteredComboBox),
      new UIPropertyMetadata(3));

    public int MinimumSearchLength
    {
        get => (int)this.GetValue(FilteredComboBox.MinimumSearchLengthProperty);
        set => SetValue(FilteredComboBox.MinimumSearchLengthProperty, value);
    }

    public TextBox PART_EditableTextBox { get; set; }

    static FilteredComboBox()
    {
        // Register a delegate to handle property changes of the Text dependency property
        ComboBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
          typeof(FilteredComboBox),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default, FilteredComboBox.FilterItemsOnTextChanged));
    }

    public FilteredComboBox()
    {
        this.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
    }

    private static void FilterItemsOnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var this_ = d as FilteredComboBox;
        this_.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        this_.Items.Filter =
          item => e.NewValue.ToString().Length < this_.MinimumSearchLength
            || ((Fruit)item).Name.Contains(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.PART_EditableTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
        this.PART_EditableTextBox.TextChanged += RemoveTextSelectionOnTextBoxTextChanged;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);

        switch (e.Key)
        {
            // Clear the filter and reset the text field
            case Key.Tab:
            case Key.Enter:
                this.Items.Filter = null;
                this.PART_EditableTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                break;
            case Key.Down:
                this.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RemoveTextSelectionOnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PART_EditableTextBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            this.PART_EditableTextBox.CaretIndex = e.Changes.FirstOrDefault()?.Offset + 1
                                                   ?? this.PART_EditableTextBox.Text.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

And am implementing it in a test solution like so;

```
<local:FilteredComboBox
        MinimumSearchLength="2"
        IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}"
        DisplayMemberPath = "Name">
    </local:FilteredComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the text of the edit `TextBox` as long there is a `SelectedItem` value assigned. The `ComboBox` internally tracks the changes of the edit text box to synchronize it with a matching item, when the control `ComboBox.IsEditable` is set to `true`. Changes that occurred during the `ComboBox.Text` change process are reverted/aborted. Deleting the current `SelectedItem` reference may help, but in most cases this isn't desirable.
It seems reasonable to execute the filtering before or after the internal lookup process. For this purpose I recommend to register a `PropertyChangedCallback` with the `ComboBox.TextProperty`. The edit text box is synchronized with the `ComboBox.Text` property, where the `ComboBox.Text` changes first to trigger the internal `ComboBox` selected item matching process.

I think there is some optimization potential:

- You shouldn't call `FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild` in the get method of the `EditableTextBox` property (calculated property). This results in a template lookup for every property read access, although the returned element will never change. You should call `FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild` once in the `FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate` override and store the instance in a private property.
- You shouldn't operate on the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, but on the `ItemsControl.Items` property instead. `ItemsControl.Items` returns a `ItemCollection`, which already implements a `ICollectionView`. Use the `ItemsControl.Items` property to sort, group or filter the items (without affecting the original source collection).
- Instead of executing the filtering on key presses, you should listen to the text changes (as suggested before).
- Some key events are redundant: *Esc* and *Enter* will by default close the dropdown

The fixed and refactored `FilteredComboBox` control could look as followed:

```
public class FilteredComboBox : ComboBox
{
  #region Dependency properties

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumSearchLengthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "MinimumSearchLength",
      typeof(int),
      typeof(FilteredComboBox),
      new UIPropertyMetadata(3));

  [Description("Length of the search string that triggers filtering.")]
  [Category("Filtered ComboBox")]
  [DefaultValue(1)]
  public int MinimumSearchLength
  {
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    get => (int)GetValue(FilteredComboBox.MinimumSearchLengthProperty);

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    set => SetValue(FilteredComboBox.MinimumSearchLengthProperty, value);
  }

  private static object CoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
  {
    var this_ = d as FilteredComboBox;
    this_.CaretIndexBeforeDropDownOpen = this_.PART_EditableTextBox.CaretIndex;
    return baseValue;
  }

  #endregion

  static FilteredComboBox()
  {
    ComboBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(FilteredComboBox),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default, FilteredComboBox.OnTextChanged));
    ComboBox.IsDropDownOpenProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(FilteredComboBox),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, null, FilteredComboBox.CoerceValue));
  }

  public FilteredComboBox()
  {
    this.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
    this.DropDownOpened += RemoveTextSelectionOnDropDownOpened;
  }

  private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var this_ = d as FilteredComboBox;
    this_.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    if (FilteredComboBox.IsNavigating)
    {
      FilteredComboBox.IsNavigating = false;
      return;
    }

    this_.Items.Filter = item => this_.PART_EditableTextBox.Text.Length < this_.MinimumSearchLength
                                 || ((Fruit) item).Name.Contains(this_.PART_EditableTextBox.Text);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this_.PART_EditableTextBox.Text))
    {
      this_.ForceTextSiteSync();
    }
  }

  private void ForceTextSiteSync()
  {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
      () =>
      {
        object currentItem = this.SelectedItem;
        this.SelectedItem = null;
        this.SelectedItem = currentItem;
        this.Items.Filter = null;
      },
      DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
  }

  private void RemoveTextSelectionOnDropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.IsSelectionBoxHighlighted)
    {
      this.PART_EditableTextBox.CaretIndex = this.CaretIndexBeforeDropDownOpen;
    }
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    FilteredComboBox.IsNavigating = true;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    this.PART_EditableTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnPreviewKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewKeyUp(e);
    this.IsDropDownOpen = true;

    switch (e.Key)
    {
      case Key.Back when string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PART_EditableTextBox.Text):
      case Key.Delete when string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PART_EditableTextBox.Text):
        ForceTextSiteSync();
        break;
      case Key.Tab:
      case Key.Enter:
        this.Items.Filter = null;
        ForceTextSiteSync();
        break;
    }
  }

  private TextBox PART_EditableTextBox { get; set; }
  private int CaretIndexBeforeDropDownOpen { get; set; }
  private static bool IsNavigating { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, thank you for the explaination and updated code! I'm going to do some tests now.

Comment: A couple of strange behaviours I spotted; pressing the down key twice with no text will leave one result in the dropdown. You must press any key to get the full list back despite text being empty. The other issue I noticed is if you backspace after selecting an item then try to reselect that item it will not populate the textbox. You need to select another item, then select that item again.

Comment: Looking into issue two here, it appears that behind the scenes the combo still considers the last item selected which is actually good behaviour so this can be ignored. I'm currently trying to fix the behaviour RE pressing down key.

Comment: Found something else strange, with no text input it misbehaves also. Steps: Click an item in the list, this item is selected but list is not filtered (this is ok behaviour). Now click a new item from the list, list is filtered down to this item but no item is currently selected anymore. Strange...

Comment: This was just meant to provide a raw example and not a complete solution. But I will take look (later). Let me know if you find other unexpected behavior.

Comment: I understand and it is still very much appreciated. I think the following seems to resolve the issues stated above. Replacing the two instances of `this_.PART_EditableTextBox.Text` with `e.NewValue.ToString()` in `FilterItemsOnTextChanged`. Let me know what you think when you have time. Thanks!

Comment: Pressing down/up after having previously selected an item seems to work oddly. Still testing.

Comment: I have updated the code (but not tested it thoroughly). The prolem with the `ComboBox` is that it has some complex logic going on that you can't simply disable. You have to use "force" to override some behavior. Some issues should be fixed.